# jQuery .load() not loading at top need to scroll up

Tags: jquery

When you click on the links it loads the correct file, but if you are in the #right and   scroll down and then click a different link it won't load at the top and you must scroll to the top. Any ideas on how to make it load at the top of the #right when you click on any link?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

    #left,#right{
        width:500px;
        height:100px;   
        overflow: scroll;
        overflow-x:hidden;
        float:left;
    }
</style>

<div id="left">
<ul>
    <li><a class="page" id="one" href="one.html">One</a></li>
    <li><a class="page" id="two" href="two.html">Two</a></li>
    <li><a class="page" id="three" href="three.html">Three</a></li>
    <li><a class="page" href="#">lskf</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
<div id="right"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('.page').click(function(e){  
        e.preventDefault();  
        var pg = $(this).attr('id');  
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href');  
        var goin = $('#right').load(toLoad);      
        switch (pg){  
            case 'one':   
            goin;  
            break;  
            case 'two':  
            goin;  
            break;  
            case 'three':  
            goin;  
            break;    
            default: $('#right').load('test.html');  
                            break;  

        }  

    });  
});   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can scroll to top after page was loaded,

```
    var goin = $('#right').load(toLoad, function() {
        $(this).scrollTop(0);
    });
```

Comment: wow, I thought I had tried that before. But now it's working... lol   Thanks :)